# I Need help installing android 6.0 marshmellow on a lg gpad f v495 tablet?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, updates, lg

I did try the automatic way by going under settings, about device, and clicking the update device button, but I received a message that the tablet is currently up to date, even though it's android 5, and has not updated since Oct 28 2015. I could not find a actual apk to just download to install myself and I can't find any help other than geek squad that said the would do it for $40.00, but that is out of the question since I have to update 3 of these tablets, any help would be great.

Comment: Not all devices receive all updates. Usually, manufacturers drop that support pretty soon: you're lucky if they still send updates after the warranty period. As I know LG, your device has long dropped from the update list. For more details, take a look at our [updates tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/updates/info).